# How to Disconnect VPN in Windows Via Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-10, vpn

I'm always connecting and disconnecting to my VPN and I have a powershell script that connects to the VPN profile and it's brilliant. I dont have to type anything just run it.

However, I always needed to disconnected via the convoluted GUI.

The awesome script I use to connect goes something like:

```
$vpnName = "MyVPN";
    $vpn = Get-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName;
    if($vpn.ConnectionStatus -eq "Disconnected"){
    rasdial $vpnName;
    }
```

Is there a way to do the opposite?

I cannot seem to find any way of disconnecting via powershell. I cannot use third party software and I can't seem to find anything in PS get-help Vpnconnection that disconnects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`rasdial` has a parameter `/DISCONNECT` that should do what you want.

You could rewrite your script to do the disconnect like this:

```
$vpnName = "MyVPN";
$vpn = Get-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName;

if($vpn.ConnectionStatus -eq "Connected"){
  rasdial $vpnName /DISCONNECT;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: That Worked, thanks. just a bit annoying that it's not listed in get-help.

Comment: No problem! I figured out the /disconnect parameter by running "rasdial /?". Usually /? prints some sort of general information for command line tools in Windows.